# Trigger an event in shiny when a variable exceeds a threshold

Tags: r, events, shiny, reactive-programming

I have a continuous variable (the zoom on a leaflet map) and I want to activate some action (polygon drawing) only when this variable exceeds a given threshold (only at after a given zoom level).

Here is a similar - but simpler and easier to reproduce - toy problem:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  sliderInput("slider", label='a number', min=100, max=400, value = 150),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$slider > 200, {
    output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(rnorm(10000), rnorm(10000)))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The problem is that, because of `Shiny`'s reactivity system, the plot (in the toy problem) or the map (in the real problem) keep being updated, even though I would like them to be updated **only when** the threshold is passed, in either direction.

I tried constructions with `observeEvent`, `eventReactive`, `reactiveValues`, etc. mixed with `if ... else` declarations. But is seems like whenever an input is updated, it triggers the whole chain of events, regardless of whether the dependent variables have changed or not. In the toy problem, it does not matter that `input$slider > 200` stays `TRUE` when `input$slider` goes from `100` to `101`, it triggers the plotting anyways.

Please tell me I am wrong!

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using `observeEvent()`, you could use a regular `observe()` and use the condition for an if statement and simply `return()` if the condition fails.

Something like

```
observe({
    if (input$slider <= 200) return()
    ...
})
```

**EDIT:** In the comments you wanted to somehow track the last value. Here's how you can do this.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sliderInput("slider", "Slider", 1, 500, 100)
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  values <- reactiveValues(last = 0)
  observe({
    if (input$slider <= 200 & values$last > 200) {
      cat("check!")
    }
    values$last <- input$slider
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: If I use `observe({output$plot <- if (input$slider <= 200) renderPlot(plot(rnorm(10000), rnorm(10000))) else return()})` as I understand you suggest, it does not change the problem: the code inside observe is still triggered and the plot is updated even if the slider moves from `101` to `102`. I want the code to be executed *only when* the threshold is passed.

Comment: If we had access to the previous value of the slider, then your solution would work. We could do something like `if (input$slider <= 200 & last(input$slider)>200)`.

Comment: if you want the last value of the slider, you could store it using `reactiveValues`()

Answer (score 0):

So, inspired by @daattali and our discussion, one possible solution is to use a `reactiveValue` to store the last value of the slider in order to test when the threshold is passed in either directions. The test itself is carried inside an `observe` function:

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(
  sliderInput("slider", label='a number', min=100, max=400, value = 150),
  plotOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(rnorm(10000), rnorm(10000)))
  last        <- reactiveValues(value = 0)
  observe({
    if ((input$slider <= 200 & last$value > 200)|(input$slider > 200 & last$value <= 200)) {
      output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(rnorm(10000), rnorm(10000)))
    }
    last$value <- input$slider
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With this solution, I correctly have an update only when the threshold (200 on the slider) is passed in either directions.